# How to convert a string 'YEARWEEK' with STR_TO_DATE to a correct date?

Tags: mysql, date-format, sql-date-functions

I am trying to convert values like `201701` to `2017-01-01` which is the first day of the first week of 2017, I have tried this

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('201701', '%Y%v')
```

because `DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y%v')` works like `YEARWEEK()` does, but instead of getting the first day of the corresponding week I get

```
2017-00-00
```

which isn't even a valid date of course.

Comment: Please vote up if answer meet your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_ADD(MAKEDATE(LEFT(d, 4), 1),
        INTERVAL RIGHT(d, 2) - 1 WEEK)
FROM
    (SELECT '201701' d) t
```

`MAKEDATE()` generate given day of the year (in this case 1st). and add weeks offset to it to get week's start.

Answer (score 0):

If you add 'Monday' to beneath script in some way, you get what you are looking for I guess (the date of the first day of the specified week).

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('201701 Monday',
'%X%V %W')
--returns: 2017-01-02
```

PS: 2017-1-1 (Sunday) is in week 52 of 2016. 2017-1-2 (Monday) is in week 1 of 2017. Weeks start on Mondays.